# print an array with separators and final symbol

Tags: python, arrays, printing

I would like to print an array in python with separators equal to `&` and '//' in the end of a row. so I can use that array in Latex.
I have try to use `np.array2string` but I haven´t succeed, so can anybody teach me a way to print an array with `separators=& and '//'` in the end of the row.
I won´t like to save the array as a txt or csv file. 
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
>>> "&".join(arr) + '//'
'a&b&c//'
```

This gets what you described.

Comment: yes, but I have an array wich size is 18*18 and his type is float64, so this solution didn´t work very well, can you help me with that?